# PHP image upload script hack or login bypass?

Tags: php, security, upload, sql-injection

one of my websites that is in an hosting space was attacked yesterday, the hacker via email says me that one product image was changed with another image file. This was true beacause he putted his signature over the old image (file substitution).
Is in this upload script some security bug?

```html
    <?php ini_set("memory_limit", "200000000"); // for large images so that we do not get "Allowed memory exhausted"?>
<?php
include_once("configlogin.php");
include("funz.php");

// Check user logged in already:
checkLoggedIn("yes"); 

// upload the file
if ((isset($_POST["submitted_form"])) && ($_POST["submitted_form"] == "image_upload_form")) {

$idimg=$_POST['idimg'];
 
 // file needs to be jpg,gif,bmp,x-png and 4 MB max
 if (($_FILES["image_upload_box"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") && ($_FILES["image_upload_box"]["size"] < 4000000))
 {
  
  
  // QUI SCELGO LA DIMENSIONE FINALE DELL'IMMAGINE AL RESIZE
  $max_upload_width = 800;
  $max_upload_height = 600;
    
  // if user chosed properly then scale down the image according to user preferances
  if(isset($_REQUEST['max_width_box']) and $_REQUEST['max_width_box']!='' and $_REQUEST['max_width_box']<=$max_upload_width){
   $max_upload_width = $_REQUEST['max_width_box'];
  }    
  if(isset($_REQUEST['max_height_box']) and $_REQUEST['max_height_box']!='' and $_REQUEST['max_height_box']<=$max_upload_height){
   $max_upload_height = $_REQUEST['max_height_box'];
  } 

  
  // if uploaded image was JPG/JPEG
  if($_FILES["image_upload_box"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["image_upload_box"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"){ 
   $image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["image_upload_box"]["tmp_name"]);
  }  
  // if uploaded image was GIF
  if($_FILES["image_upload_box"]["type"] == "image/gif"){ 
   $image_source = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES["image_upload_box"]["tmp_name"]);
  } 
  // BMP doesn't seem to be supported so remove it form above image type test (reject bmps) 
  // if uploaded image was BMP
  if($_FILES["image_upload_box"]["type"] == "image/bmp"){ 
   $image_source = imagecreatefromwbmp($_FILES["image_upload_box"]["tmp_name"]);
  }   
  // if uploaded image was PNG
  if($_FILES["image_upload_box"]["type"] == "image/x-png"){
   $image_source = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES["image_upload_box"]["tmp_name"]);
  }
  
  

  $remote_file = "../immaginiprodotti/".$_FILES["image_upload_box"]["name"];
  imagejpeg($image_source,$remote_file,100);
  chmod($remote_file,0644);
 
 

  // get width and height of original image
  list($image_width, $image_height) = getimagesize($remote_file);
 
  if($image_width>$max_upload_width || $image_height >$max_upload_height){
   $proportions = $image_width/$image_height;
   
   if($image_width>$image_height){
    $new_width = $max_upload_width;
    $new_height = round($max_upload_width/$proportions);
   }  
   else{
    $new_height = $max_upload_height;
    $new_width = round($max_upload_height*$proportions);
   }  
   
   
   $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width , $new_height);
   $image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($remote_file);
   
   imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image_source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height);
   imagejpeg($new_image,$remote_file,100);
   
   imagedestroy($new_image);
  }
  
  imagedestroy($image_source);
  
  
  rename ($remote_file, "../immaginiprodotti/$idimg.jpg");
  
  header("Location: prodotti.php");
  exit;
 }
 else{
  header("Location: prodotti.php");
  exit;
 }
}
?>



    checkPass($login, $password) {

     $login= mysql_real_escape_string($login);
  $password= mysql_real_escape_string($password);
  
  $login=addslashes($login);
  $password=addslashes($password);
 
 global $link;
 
 $query="SELECT login, password FROM users WHERE login='$login' and password='$password'";
 $result=mysql_query($query, $link)
  or die("checkPass fatal error: ".mysql_error());
 

 // Check exactly one row is found:
 if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1 AND !preg_match("[a-z0-9]", $login)  AND !preg_match("[a-z0-9]", $password ) ) {
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
  return $row;
 }
 //Bad Login:
 return false;
} // end func checkPass($login, $password)
```

The second part of the script is the login control function (from the included config file)
is possible too to bypass this checkPass() function via sql-injection to enter directly to the upload protected page?

Thanx

Comment: Think this question would be better suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is not possible to bypass that function. What is possible is to retrieve the passwords via sql inyection as you did mention and use that user/pass in the checkPass function...

Comment: you means to say attacker able to upload there script from your file uploading field right ??

Answer (score 3):

Your code is hideously insecure. You are **DIRECTLY** using the **USER-SUPPLIED** filename as your target "write to this file" name. It is TRIVIAL for a user to specify a full path in there and your code will happily scribble their image ANYWHERE on your sever they want:

```
    $remote_file = "../immaginiprodotti/".$_FILES["image_upload_box"]["name"];
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    imagejpeg($image_source,$remote_file,100);
```

e.g. consider someone faking up an upload and doing the equivalent of

```
 image_upload_box['name'] = '../../../../../../home/sites/example.com/imgs/site-logo.jpg';
```

You are also vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com):

This line makes password "safe":

```
 $password= mysql_real_escape_string($password);
```

And them for some unknown reason you DOUBLE-escape the string with addslashes():

```
 $password=addslashes($password);
```

which re-opens injection vulnerability. addslashes() is utterly useless moronic garbage. You should surgically remove any knowledge of its existence from your brain. It is NOT unicode-aware, and WILL allow injection attacks.

Beyond that, the mysql_*() functions are obsolete/deprecated, and you should scrap all of this code and start from scratch with mysqli (note the `i`) or PDO, using proper prepared statements and placeholders.

Your `preg_match()` call is also incorrect, making the entire regex useless. You also TRY to do the regex tests AFTER you've done addslashes, whcih means a proper name like `Miles O'Brien` would get rejected, because addlashes/real_escape_string will have turned it into `Miles O\\'Brien` and will get rejected.

Comment: Did you actually try the file path thing yourself? Because [PHP uses `basename` on the supplied file name](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/rfc1867.c#L1138).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But how modify the code above with mysqli or pdo starting from the original script and data post transferring? and the upload how put it safely? how to modify it?